# SECURITY BY USERS POWER BI

Tags: security, powerbi, multiple-users

I would like to know some Security parametrers in power BI.

**Q1/** I have one matrix as a visual object in one report in power bi

**COLUMN1**  |  **COLUMN2**  | **COLUMN 3**

PEN          |  BLUE         | SMALL

RUBBER       |  WHITE        | BIG

PC           |  BLACK        | BIG

I have **two users** for this report: **ANTHONY@BUSINESS.COM** & **CHARLES@BUSINESS.COM**

I want that when **ANTHONY@BUSINESS.COM** enter in the power bi app to this report just can see the column 1 (like it is one kind of security level that i do not know how to do)

Then, when **CHARLES@BUSINESS.COM** enter to the same report he will ne able to see the three columns.

**IMPORTANT: CANNOT BE FILTER, NEED TO BE SOME KIND OF SECURITY LEVEL O PARAMETRER.**

Thank you so much in advanced :)

Comment: Object level security is what you are looking for but it is Premium only
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/object-level-security-ols-now-available-for-public-preview-in-power-bi-premium/

Comment: Beware that many users will vote down if you SHOUT, especially in the title but possibly also in the text. Don't ever use all-cap titles and try and refrain from using ALL CAPS or **bold** in the body.